# Wire type for outdoor sub panel

Tags: wiring, subpanel

I am adding an exterior 120v, 100 amp sub panel 2' from the existing service panel. I am going to use #2 individual, stranded copper wire in schedule 40 raceway.

My question is: what "type" wire sould I use. What would the wire abbreviation and description be?

Comment: That's dedication when even the user name is in all caps.  Please use proper capitalization and punctuation when posing questions.

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense to install only a 120V 100A panel. In fact, It is unlikely you will even find a single-pole 100A breaker. WHY are you considering that?

Comment: Thanks Speedy Petey.  This sub panel is to be dedicated to a 5th wheel trailer.  I want to come off the sub with a 120v, 30 amp circuit, and (4) 120v, 15 amp circuits which will be pedestaled  near the 5th wheel.

Comment: @Speedy, after more study, I understand your "makes absolutely no sense" comment.  I will run 3 conductors to the sub panel.  Thanks.

Comment: Make it a 60amp (or even 40amp) 240v sub panel. Put the 120v 30a circuit on one leg and the three 120v 15a circuits on the other. That'll be cheaper. BTW, you need to run **four** wires: hot1, hot2, neutral, and ground. Because it's a sub, you need to keep the ground and neutral separated.

Comment: @Doxy, will go with a 60 amp, 240v sub.  Will use 6 Gauge wire in conduit.

Comment: @Doxy, will use cable in conduit.  What would be the cable type?

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting individual wires, it would normally be called "2 Gauge THHN".  You can also write it as *#2*, but I think the "abbreviation" you're looking for is THHN which stands for "Thermoplastic High Heat-resistant Nylon".  You may also see references to THWN, where the "W" means it's rated for wet conditions, but it's the same general type of wire.

Comment: @RICHO "Thanks" is normally given with the little up arrows next to the "score" of an answer (which in this case is still a zero).  Comments also have up arrows for thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since the conduit will be outside, its likely to be considered a wet location. So you'll need wires rated for wet locations, such as THWN.

You'll probably see it sold as THHN/THWN/TWN75/T90, THWN-2, or MTW. It's important to make sure whatever you get, is rated for wet locations.